# JSF 2 Partial Requests doesn't use FacesContext from the Factory

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra, facescontext

It seems like the partial requests don't use the faces context instances that are created by `FacesContextFactory` implementations.

Here's the code in `UIViewRoot#processDecodes` that indicates the same

```
if (context.getPartialViewContext().isPartialRequest() &&
    !context.getPartialViewContext().isExecuteAll()) {
    context.getPartialViewContext().processPartial(PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES);
} else {
    super.processDecodes(context);
}
```

It seems like the PartialViewContext stores the default FacesContextImpl implementation within it and uses it to call lifecycle methods. (Notice that the processPartial method doesn't take a context object, because it uses it own internally stored one)

Is this a bug or this code in there for a specific reason?

Thanks

Comment: Does it harm your logic somehow or you're just curious?

Comment: i need to use the FacesContext that i instantiate from the factory, to retrieve some additional information that is set on its instance variables.
technically speaking, i could still retrieve the raw values from the request map if i wanted to, but that would just be wierd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FacesContext` instances are unique per thread, and The `FacesServlet` creates a `ThreadLocal<FacesContext>` on the beginning of the request while acquiring the `FacesContext` (which is the contract of  `FacesContextFactory#getFacesContext)` and removes it on the end of the response associated with the HTTP servlet request (by calling the `FacesContext#release`).

Whenever you do a `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` in your JSF code, you'll always get the same instance throughout the entire HTTP servlet request/response processing.

About the method `UIViewRoot#processDecodes`,I really don't see any line which probably can indicate that method uses it's own created instance rather than the passed one. Which line made you think that?

It can be seen in the `FacesServlet#service` method that it creates the `FacesContext` from The `FacesContextFactory`, here is a excerpt from the `FacesServlet#service` method which shows this -

```
// Acquire the FacesContext instance for this request
FacesContext context = facesContextFactory.getFacesContext
   (servletConfig.getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);

// Execute the request processing lifecycle for this request
try {
 ...
} catch (FacesException e) {
 ...
}
finally {
 // Release the FacesContext instance for this request
 context.release();
}
```

Considering this, I don't feel `UIViewRoot#processDecodes` can have the `FacesContext` instance which is not from `FacesContextFactory`.

Since you're saying - you have set some additional parameters to the `FacesContext` which get returned from `FacesContextFactory`, that means you have your own custom implementation of `FacesContextFactory`, if this is the case then are you sure that your instance is injected in the `FacesServlet` and not mojarra's `com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl` (if you're using mojarra)?

Comment: looking more into the code, i realized that my custom implementation of the FacesContextFactory, does a 
`delegate.getFacesContext()`

This in turn, calls the Default Factory and initializes a PartialViewContext via the 
`ExceptionHandlerFactoryImpl#getExceptionHandler.`

I think as a solution, i would need to call 
`ctx.setExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerFactory.getExceptionHandler());` before i make the call to the delegate. Let me check and get back

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i got it to work. Below is the code in my custom faces context factory

```
public FacesContext getFacesContext(Object context, Object request, Object response, Lifecycle lifecycle) throws FacesException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    ExternalContextFactory externalContextFactory = (ExternalContextFactory) getFactory(FactoryFinder.EXTERNAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    ExternalContext externalContext = externalContextFactory.getExternalContext(context, request, response);

    // CustomFacesContext extends from FacesContextImpl
    CustomFacesContext facesContext = new CustomFacesContext(externalContext, lifecycle);

    ExceptionHandlerFactory exceptionHandlerFactory = (ExceptionHandlerFactory) getFactory(FactoryFinder.EXCEPTION_HANDLER_FACTORY);
    ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = exceptionHandlerFactory.getExceptionHandler();
    facesContext.setExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
}
```